# Workaround for Security.allowDomain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have number of SWF files which should be accessed from external server. To be able to do this I need to have Security.allowDomain in each SWF file. The problem here is that I don't have FLA for those files and there are thousands of SWFs.

If there a better way to configure those files to be accessible from other domain?
Like having some kind of config file or so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one workaround, but I think it's a security hole, so it can be fixed in any release of flash player. Meanwhile it works now so here is solution - use `URLLoader` with `BINARY` `dataFormat` as preloader for swf bytes:

swf without Security permissions for it scripting:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class astest extends MovieClip
{
    public function astest()
    {
    }

    public function externalCheck():void
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        graphics.drawCircle(100, 100, 100);
    }
}
}
```

Loader swf that wants to load previous swf and call the `externalCheck` method:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class astest2 extends MovieClip
{
    private var loader:Loader;
    private var urlLoader:URLLoader;

    public function astest2()
    {
        init();
    }

    //this method works fine
    protected function init():void
    {
        urlLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://domain_with_your_swfs/astest.swf"));

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void
        {
            addChild(loader = new Loader());

            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoader);
            loader.loadBytes(urlLoader.data as ByteArray);
        });
    }

    //this method will fire SecurityError when calling the 'externalCheck' method
    protected function init2(event:Event = null):void
    {
        addChild(loader = new Loader());

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoader);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://domain_with_your_swfs/astest.swf"));
    }

    protected function onLoader(event:Event = null):void
    {
        var swf:Object = loader.content;
        swf.externalCheck();
    }


}
}
```

Don't forget to place the `crossdomain.xml` file to the root of your server with swf files to load, without it URLLoader will not able to load the bytes, it's the only security requirement.